# Why use the notation $\in$ in Cauchy Problem?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, regularity-theory-of-pdes, semigroup-of-operators

I studyng looked in a book of Barbu a notation of type
"Cauchy Problem
$$f(t) \in \frac{dy(t)}{dt}+Ay(t), \ t \in [0,T]\\
\\
y(0)=y_0
$$
$ f \in L^1(0,T;X)$". Why the author used $\in$ and no $=$?

Comment: Could you give the precise reference of the book or give the context in which this equation appears ?

Comment: @SolubleFish Title: SolubleFish Analysis and Control of Nonlinear Infinite Dimensional Systems. Author: Viorel Barbu. Pg. 199

Comment: $A$ is a multivalued operator. The expression to the right of $\in$ is a set. Read section 2.3 as they say in the previous paragraph.

Comment: I don't have this reference but it might be an example of a "differential inclusion." https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_inclusion

Comment: @plop so it not implies the equality?